# Temporarily disable drag-function (d3js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With your help, I've created a svg-"Editor", where grouped Symbols are loaded to and from a database:

```js
var svgEditor = d3.select('#drawing');
for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    var symbol = symbols[i];
    const g = svgEditor.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + symbol.SymbolPosition + ")")
        .attr("id", symbol.SubFunctionId.toString())
        .attr("class", "draggable preview")
        .attr("pointer-events", "fill")
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended)
        );
    g.html(symbol.SVG.replace("#{BMK}", symbol.BMK));
}
```

Now I've added a functionality to draw lines in this SVG too.
My problem is that these lines should start and end directly at the symbols.
When starting a line, it could happen that instead of inserting the first x-y-coordinates, I drag the symbol beneath.
Is there any way to temporarily disable the d3-dragging function of the SVG elements before inserting the first point?

Here, I start the first point:

```js
function mouseButtonPressed(evt) {
    pointerOrigin = getPointFromEvent(evt);
    //Wheel pressed, PAN Viewbox
    if (evt.button === 1) {
        pointerDown = true;
        svgDrawing.style.cursor = 'move';
    }
    //Draw a line
    else if (evt.button === 0 && drawingLine === 1)
    {
        line = d3.select('#drawing').append('line')
            .classed(lineClass, true)
            .attr("x1", Math.round(pointerOrigin.x / raster) * raster)
            .attr("y1", Math.round(pointerOrigin.y / raster) * raster)
            .attr("x2", Math.round(pointerOrigin.x / raster) * raster)
            .attr("y2", Math.round(pointerOrigin.y / raster) * raster);

    }
    //place a new Symbol on editor
    else if (evt.button == 0 && newSymbol) {
        positionData = newSymbol.attr("transform").replace("translate(", "");
        positionData = positionData.replace(")", "");
        positionData = positionData.replace(" ", ",");
        saveSymbolPosition();
        newSymbol = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do the trick for you

```
d3.select('selector').on('mousedown.drag', null);
```

Comment: That works fine.
After line is drawn, I call this again:

    d3.selectAll('.selector')
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));